# Repeated measures analysis

Tags: regression, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis, generalized-estimating-equations

I was reading a book about  repeated measures analysis, but I really couldn't drill enough into the concept behind the math equations. In the book, it says like this:

[image]

What I can't understand is the distribution for y. You know when we talked about normal distribution for a random variable X, we defined it X ~N ( µ, σ2). But here I really don't know how to interpret vector V in normal distribution. I mean if the shape for normal distribution is as follows then what will the shape be for normal distribution with a vector V within it.

[image]

And at the end if you have come up with a better explanation for concept behind GEE, I would be really thankful to share it here.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

This distribution is an extension of the univariate normal distribution called multivariate normal distribution with parameters $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$. I guess everything you need to know about it can be found on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) (or at least this is a good starting point).